# when sending a request to the server, the node does not receive the req.body

Tags: node.js, reactjs

when sending a request to the server, the node does not receive the req.body
what could be the mistake?

react:

```
sendRequest('POST','http://127.0.0.1:5500/api/auth/register', {...form})

function sendRequest(method:string, url:string, bodyObj:any = null){
   return fetch(url, {
      method: method,
      headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
         },
      body: JSON.stringify(bodyObj)
   }).then(response => response.json())
     .then(result  => result)
}
```

node:

```
router.post('/register',async (req,res)=>{
   console.log(req.body)
   res.status(200).json(req.body)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things going on here that might cause issues but I think the primary area to investigate is the `sendRequest` function is returning a Promise which is asynchronous but then it's also trying to `.then` within that same function.

Resolving or rejecting the return promise where you want to handle the data might be a better execution.

```js
// This returns a Promise
function sendRequest(method, url, bodyObj) {
  return fetch(url, {
    method: method,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(bodyObj)
  })
}

sendRequest('POST', 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/api/auth/register', { ...form
}).then(result => {
  console.log(result)
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err)
})
```